# Platform channels not working in Google Play version of Flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-play, release, flutter-platform-channel

I have a very weird problem. When I try to launch my app on debug or release in IDE, it works, but when I download the same version of the app from google play (internal test), it launches, but when I try to do something that uses platform channels it just throws a bunch of errors saying that such platform channel is not found or doesn't exist. And this happens to every platform channel. Any ideas, what the problem might be?

Here are some errors

```
E/flutter (32560): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/package_info)
E/flutter (32560): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157)
E/flutter (32560): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32560): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:359)
E/flutter (32560): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32560): #2      PackageInfo.fromPlatform (package:package_info/package_info.dart:43)
E/flutter (32560): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32560): #3      DataHandler._asyncInitState (package:project/utils/data_handler.dart:78)
E/flutter (32560): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32560): 
E/flutter (32560): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setupPurchases on channel purchases_flutter)
E/flutter (32560): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157)
E/flutter (32560): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32560): #1      Purchases.setup (package:purchases_flutter/purchases_flutter.dart:44)
E/flutter (32560): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32560): #2      _SplashScreenState.asyncInitState (package:project/main.dart:143)
E/flutter (32560): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32560):
```

Comment: Can you add your errors to the question?